# Debian shows only a blank desktop when using compiz

Tags: debian, desktop, compiz

I have a Debian (squeeze) guest on virtualbox on a Windows 8 host. I have given it 128 MB video memory (the max allowed by vb) and 3 GB RAM. I am trying to run Compiz on it, but every time I switch to Compiz from GNOME my mouse, icons, top bar, and lower bar all go away, and I am left with a blank desktop. I have installed everything for GNOME-based compiz, followed the Debian wiki's guide to installing it, and edited all the necessary files for it to work. I tried enabling window decorations, which was supposed to fix the windows, but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong? I have 1200 MB video memory, and I have enabled 3D acceleration (vb doesn't allow 2D acceleration on non-windows guests), but are Intel integrated graphics just too crappy to run Compiz, or will it not run on virtual machine based Debian?

Answer (score 2):

I am also running VirtualBox in windows 8 with debian squeeze. It's my first run so I'm still using the `twm` window manager. I'm getting the same thing as you- a blank desktop. The only time i can see anyhting is when I hold down the left mouse key(twm's ugly!). When I quit `X` server I got these error messages:

> starting VirtualBox Additions:
>    error: VbgIR3Init failed with rc=VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND failed!
>   (EE) VBoxVideo(0): Failed to intialize with VirtualBox device (rc=-102)
>    - Make sure that the VirtualBox guest additions are properly installed.
>   If you are not sure try reinstalling them. The X window graphics driver will run in compatability mode
>   FATAL: Module vboxVideo not found
>   (EE) VBoxVideo(0): DRIScreenInit failed, disabling DRI
>   SELinux: Disabled on system, not enabling in X server

Try entering text mode and note what is being displayed. If you have `DRI` disabled like mine then it would explain the blank desktop since `OpenGL` depends on [DRI(Direct Rendering Infrastructure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_infrastructure) for hardware accleration:

> DRI has also been adapted to provide  OpenGL acceleration on a framebuffer console without an X Server running.

and from the [Compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz) article:

> Internally Compiz uses the OpenGL library as the interface to the graphics hardware